# Difficulty understanding enums

Tags: vb6, enums

Why can a form have a public enum block if it cannot have a public constant declaration?

Also if I have a public variable in the declaration section of a form
I can reference it throughout the application but I MUST use dot notation
e.g form1.var1

However if I put an enum block in the declaration of a form I can reference it 
throughout the rest of the application but only if it's NOT prefixed
with the dot notation.

Are enum blocks the only structure on a form that can only or must only be referenced from outside without dot notation?

What is the logic to this that I am missing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The logic here is that an enum defines a *type*.

You already know about types because you use them everywhere. A class is a type. So is an `Integer`, a `Long`, a `String`, and all of the other built-in data types. And you can create your user user-defined types using the `Type` keyword; e.g.,

```
' Defines a new type User
Type User
    Name As String
    ID As Integer
    PhoneNumber As String
End Type
```

If you think about it, you'll see that this makes sense. You never use an enum directly. Rather, you use it as a type. You declare variables that hold a value of that enum's type, the same way as you would declare a variable that holds a value of type `Integer` or `String`.

By contrast, a constant is not a type. It is just a regular value, no different than if you had declared a regular variable, except that a constant variable's value cannot be modified.

Types can be defined anywhere, inside or outside of a class. *Variables*, however, must either be defined inside of a class or inside of a module.

Comment: Thanks, this has clarified things for me. Thinking about it an enum as a type is just a variation of type long for which some values have a second name. Is that right? It still doesn't 'feel' quite right that they can be declared in a form somehow.

Comment: A Form or UserControl is just a special kind of Class.  Classes need to be able to declare Public Enums so that they can be used as the type for properties, method arguments, method return values, etc.

Comment: @Bob77 Ah OK thanks. That makes sense to me now. Just for interest's sake, do you know if an Enum is the only structure that can be declared in a form that isn't referenced from outside using dot notation?

Comment: VB6 allows you to use shortcut syntax for Public Enums.  That means that as long as they are unique throughout the Project you don't need to qualify them with the name of the Class.  I.e. you can use `Form1.Freddy` or just `Freddy` (assuming `Freddy` is a Public Enum).  You can't do that for Properties, Methods, or Events.  Note that when you declare `Public X As Long` in a Form you have declared a Property.  `Sub` and `Function` declare Methods, and could be either Private or Public.  VB6 is far more object oriented than people give it credit for.

Comment: @Bob77 Can I just say that you can't use Form1.Freddy you can only use Freddy! Form1.Freddy gives an error.

Comment: One can use `Feddy.EnumItem` or `EnumItem` only if it's unique project/module wise.

Answer (score 3):

The reason for this behaviour is due to VB6 being underlied by COM. The majority of VB types are based on those available to a COM type library (which are contained in all VB components, and most general "ActiveX" components). Public VB Enum statements are equivalent to the "Enum" found in a type library. However, in type libraries, Enums are top level objects (other objects include Interface, CoClass, Module, Record, Union and Alias). This means that VB accesses them as <ProjectName>.<Enum Name>, and this convention is applied to enumerated types created internally. The VB object browser is misleading when it says Form1.MyEnum - that is just saying where it is declared.

As for constants - unfortunately this is functional hole in VB6. COM type libraries *do* support constants as part of a type library Module, but this ability was never added to VB6 (possibly because VB doesn't have a concept of a type library Module).

Comment: Thanks for the info, love to know where you learn this stuff!

Comment: I think that I worked this one out for myself. However, the background I obtained from two books: Hardcore Visual Basic by Bruce McKinney (http://vb.mvps.org/hardcore/) and "Advanced Visual Basic 6" by Matt Curland (http://www.powervb.com/).